# Whats is the default password for an application created with railsapps

Tags: railsapps

What's the initial password for the "user@example.com" of a "railsapps" application?

```
noname_development=# select * from users;
 id |      email       |                      encrypted_password                      | reset_password_token | reset_password_sent_at | remember_created_at |         created_at         |         updated_at         | name | confirmation_token |       confirmed_at        | confirmation_sent_at | unconfirmed_email | role | invitation_token | invitation_created_at | invitation_sent_at | invitation_accepted_at | invitation_limit | invited_by_type | invited_by_id | invitations_count 
----+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------+--------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------
  1 | user@example.com | $2a$11$BUd5P4WM0fbjykUwhaIW/.tBCM1b0a2fI3UWMUYAhxGICW59YExbm |                      |                        |                     | 2019-01-16 19:39:17.371911 | 2019-01-16 19:39:17.382413 |      |                    | 2019-01-16 19:39:17.37032 |                      |                   |    2 |                  |                       |                    |                        |                  |                 |               |                 0
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The default password for any RailsApp example application for "user@example.com" is "changeme". This is documented in the README file for any of the RailsApp example applications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with 'password'?

Comment: come to think of it, my coworker may have changed it